# UDP Client support for android apps

Tags: android, delphi, udp, client

I have recently upgraded from XE3 to Tokyo 10.2 with the intention of learning a little about Android apps.  Quite some time ago I wrote a very basic vcl app for wake on lan.  I though that maybe a nice project to get me started, would be to re-design and recode my WOL project to run under Android from my phone.  All the basics worked really well.  Layout good on many Android phones - all validation of IP's and MAC addresses work well.  However, am I missing something - I cannot find a UDP Client to support Android in 10.2 .  This is so frustrating as I thought I was doing really well.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How about TIdUDPClient and TIdUDPServer?

Comment: Thanks Dave - a reinstall of Tokyo was needed to get the Indy Clients / Servers to show as available for Android  - not sure what the problem was - However I am now struggling to get the desired bytes sent.  I want to send FFFFFFFFFFFF + 16 iterations of 647002226173 (Mac Address)